# Testing HPC service written using Microsoft HPC SOA API

Tags: c#, testing, service, soa, hpc

How can I, on my local machine (which is obviously a non Windows Server 2012) test the SOA service that I have developed using Microsoft HPC SOA service API of HPC Pack 2012R, before actually deploying it to the Windows Server 2012 test environment?

In my first attempt to do that I tried to install the HPC Server component on my machine but it failed and asked for Windows Server 2012 OS.

Comment: it's a bit concerning that no one has replied. I *think* I am asking the right question, so I would've thought that either get a "no you can't do that" sort of reponse or a pointer about how I can do that? It's also a bit concerning that maybe not many people are using this technology? maybe its obsolete or something...?

Comment: I have found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497656/can-i-emulate-ms-compute-cluster-server-on-my-dev-machine), and have now started installing Hyper-V and windows servers locally in order to do the tests. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install) is how to install Hyper-V on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

HPC Pack only runs on windows server family. Only workstation node can be deployed on non-server windows. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791806(v=ws.11).aspx) is os requirement of latest HPC Pack 2016.